# validate input cmdline input argv[] contains all integers

Tags: c, validation, integer, char

So I have an assignment dealing with number manipulation that also includes error checking. I'm having issues with the error checking side. A user uses the application by via commandline and giving 8 numbers that are space separated. I am having a problem validating that the data provided are actually integers.

I was suggested to use the method strtol() however I know that if the integer is invalid, it returns a 0, but I need to return an error message instead of a 0 because 0 is valid. Is there another method I can use to validate input?

Comment: `strtol` **does not** return a 0 if the integer is invalid; read the function description attentively. It does however return a `long`. You need to make sure the value fits within `int` range. Hint: use `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtol` do not have only its return value to signal an error in the conversion, it has also its second parameter (`endptr` in my manpage); if you pass to it a pointer to a `char *`, it will store there the position of the first character that it couldn't convert, or will leave it alone if nothing could be converted. Thus, you have the following cases:

```
char * endptr=NULL;
int out=strtol(yourstring, &endptr, 10);
if(endptr==NULL)
{
    /* the whole string is garbage - no numbers extracted */
}
else if(*endptr==0)
{
    /* the whole string was a number - yay! */
}
else
{
    /* strtol extracted a number from the string, but stopped at some invalid character
       that you can check by looking at the value of endptr */
}
```

Moreover, you can also check the value to which `strtol` sets `errno` in case of problems; `EINVAL` is used if nothing could be extracted, the other values can be seen on the manpage of `strtol`.

You can also use `sscanf` and check its return value to quickly see if the string could or could not be converted to `int` (or to whatever you set in the format string).

Answer (score 1):

If `strtol()` encounters an error, it will set `errno` to `EINVAL`.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol):

> #### Return Value
>
> The **`strtol()`** function returns the result of the conversion, unless the value would underflow or overflow. ...In both cases, **`errno`** is set to **`ERANGE`**. ...
>
> #### Errors
>
> **`EINVAL`**...The given base contains an unsupported value. ...
>
> The implementation may also set **`errno`** to **`EINVAL`** in case no conversion was performed (no digits seen, and 0 returned).

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments are strings, why not use [`isdigit(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/isupper.3.html)?

Comment: Maybe because that wouldn't check for out-of-bounds numbers. And you had to check for a leading `-` separately.

Comment: What are "out-of-bounds" integers?

Comment: for a 32-bit integer type, 10000000000000000000000000 is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Who said anything about any bit-width?

Comment: The original poster was suggested to use `strtol` for checking. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use `strtol` properly, you have to reset `errno` before calling it. And if you write code that you want to reuse in other projects, that code should have no unintended side-effects. So there are two variants: a simple one that is probably good enough in your case, and a complex one that would be acceptable in a library of reusable code.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* the simple variant, with the side-effect of changing errno */
static bool is_long_1(const char *s)
{
  char *end;

  errno = 0;
  strtol(s, &end, 10);
  return errno == 0 && *end == '\0';
}

/* the complex variant, without side-effects */
static bool is_long_2(const char *s)
{
  char *end;
  int saved_errno = errno;
  errno = 0;

  strtol(s, &end, 10);
  bool succeeded = errno == 0 && *end == '\0';
  errno = saved_errno;
  return succeeded;
}
```

Using one of these functions for checking your arguments should be quite easy, so I leave that part to you to find out.